# Get distinct count of id in a set of days (on a particular date and previous 2 days)

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark

I have 4 columns in my table, rii, uii, rdi and udi. Just like below:

```
+----------+------+----------+------+
|       rdi|   rii|       udi|   uii|
+----------+------+----------+------+
|2002-02-06|1376.Q|2002-02-06|1376.Q|
|2002-02-28|1376.Q|2002-02-28|1376.Q|
|2002-03-06|1376.Q|2002-03-06|1376.Q|
|2002-02-01|1792.T|2002-02-01|1792.T|
|2002-03-07|1802.T|2002-03-07|1802.T|
|2002-03-08|1802.T|2002-03-08|1802.T|
|2002-04-03|1802.T|2002-04-03|1802.T|
|2002-03-07|1805.T|2002-03-07|1805.T|
|2002-02-18|1810.T|2002-02-18|1810.T|
|2002-03-22|1821.T|2002-03-22|1821.T|
|2002-02-27|1862.T|2002-02-27|1862.T|
|2002-04-11|1878.T|2002-04-11|1878.T|
|2002-04-18|1884.T|2002-04-18|1884.T|
|2002-02-27|1899.T|2002-02-27|1899.T|
|2002-03-11|1924.T|2002-03-11|1924.T|
|2002-02-05|1925.T|2002-02-05|1925.T|
|2002-01-23|1926.T|2002-01-23|1926.T|
|2002-03-19|1926.T|2002-03-19|1926.T|
|2002-01-25|1942.T|2002-01-25|1942.T|
|2002-01-31|1942.T|2002-01-31|1942.T|
+----------+------+----------+------+
```

i just want to get the number of unique rii on a logic like if i give lookback as 2 then it should give unique number of rii in a set of days (on that particular rdi and in previous 2 days from rdi)

so i give the lookback as 2 then, my result should be like (for rdi = 2002-02-06, it should find the unique rii in rdi in (2002-02-06,2002-02-05,2002-02-04))

```
+----------+-------------+----------+------+
|       rdi|          rii|       udi|   uii|
+----------+-------------+----------+------+
|2002-02-06|1376.Q,1925.T|2002-02-06|1376.Q|
```

I tried with the below query, but not getting the required o/p

```
select count(distinct uii) as u,
  rdi,
  (select count(distinct rii) from `mytable` where rdi between DATE_SUB(rdi, INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND rdi) as r
  from `mytable`
  group by rdi 
  order by rdi;
```

check my fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01411/37)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to associate each record to records from previous days:

```
select t1.rdi, 
       group_concat(t2.rii) as rii, 
       t1.udi,
       count(distinct t2.uii)
from `mytable` as t1
left join `mytable` as t2
   on t2.rdi between DATE_SUB(t1.rdi, INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND t1.rdi
group by rdi 
order by rdi;
```

**Output:**

[image]

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01411/46)

Comment: this really worked, need to check it with main dataset, Thank you so much. really helpful, if you suggest, what was your think process about this problem. Thanks

Comment: @ggupta The key idea is to relate each record to the subset of records that fall within the current date and previous 2 days. You get a lot of duplicates this way, but this is no problem as you only want to do a `count distinct`.

Comment: you basically break the problem into small problem, but i dint have good exposure to left join. Thank you Giorgos